# Google Apps scriptでGmailを送る（複数ファイルを添付したい）

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

やりたいこと：GoogleAppsScriptで複数ファイル添付をしてメールを送信したいと考えています。

現在シートにはメールアドレスのリストが1列、CCが1列、各フォルダIDが一列、メールの件名・本文などのセルを用意しています。

以下のコードで

1. シートの範囲を変数に格納して
2. for文を使って、件名、本文置換作業、ファイル取得・添付を1つのループで
3. 件名、本文の置換作業、ファイルの取得・添付ができたので送信

としたいのですが、ファイル添付がされません・・・
エラーはなく、メールは届いてます。

フォルダ・ファイルをどのように取得しているかなどの知識が不足しているのだろうと思うのですが、調べても考えても沼にはまってしまっているのでどうかお力添えいただけますと幸いです。。。

```
  //シート取得
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("＃＃＃");
  const recipients = sh.getRange(1, 2, sh.getLastRow()-1, sh.getLastColumn()-1).getValues();

  //送信
  for (recipient of recipients) {
    let subject = sh.getRange("＃").getValue();
    let body = sh.getRange("＃").getValue();
    const folderId = recipient[＃]
    const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)
    const files = folder.getFiles()
    var attachementsFiles = []
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      const file = files.next();  
      attachementsFiles.push(file);
    }
    body = body.replace("＃＃＃", recipient[＃]);
    body = body.replace("＃＃＃", recipient[＃]);
    body = body.replace("＃＃＃", recipient[＃]);
    const options = {
       cc : recipient[＃],
       "attachements" : attachementsFiles
    };
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient[＃], subject, body, options);
  }
  }
```

[image: recipientの元データはこんな感じです。消す必要がありこんなもので恐縮ですが、どうぞよろしくお願いします。]

Comment: シートの実データのサンプルもあった方が原因を特定しやすいと思います (必要に応じて一部を伏せ字にするのは構いません)

Comment: ご指摘いただき有難うございます。写真を追加させていただきました、どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> const file = files.next();
> attachementsFiles.push(attachementsFiles);

これは

```
attachementsFiles.push(file);
```

ですね。

そして

> "attachements" : attachementsFiles

これは

```
attachments : attachementsFiles
```

ですね。attachmentsのスペルの間違いです。

Comment: ItagakiFumihiko様
有難うございます。
間違いのご指摘いただき有難うございます。

ただ修正してもやはり、送信時にファイル添付はされていませんでした。
試しにConsole.log（attachments);を打ってみたところ、 [ {}, {}, {}, {} ]が返ってきました。中身が入っていないようです・・・

Comment: attachementsFiles.push(file.getName()); ですね。
回答も編集しました。

Comment: ご返信いただき有難うございます。
getNameで名前を取ってくることができるのでログも表示されるのですが・・・逆に名前のみ取得していてファイルそのものを取ってきていないような動きになります。

console.logは無事ファイルの名前がすべて表示されますが、
メールにはやはりファイルの添付はない状態です。。

Comment: すみません。fileで良かったですね。そして添付されない理由がわかりました。回答を編集しておきました。

Comment: 本当ですね、、スペルミスお恥ずかしいです。ご指摘有難うございます。後ほど試してみます。